# In a bash script, how to I remove all double quotes within a JSON data set {}, between the double quotes

Tags: json, linux, bash

I have a massive 20GB JSON file with realty records.

example snippet

```
{"id":2545,"name":"No cribs (infant beds) available"},{"description": "Here is some text with a <a href=\"stupidurl.com\">click here</a>"}
```

I am trying to use a WHILE loop in bash to read the file line by line and extract only the data I want into a new, smaller file for later processing.

```
while read line; do
        #All this If Statement does is look for a pattern to identify the line I want to save 
        if [[ ($line == *"\"country_code\":\"US\","* ]]; then

            echo $line  >> $JSON_FILE_FILTERED
        fi

    done < $JSON_FILE
```

My issues are that that echo statement removes the escaped quotes.

```
href=\"mylink\"
```

becomes...

```
href="mylink"
```

...in the new JSON file which causes JQ parsing errors.

I need to either remove the double quotes within the JSON Brackets or figure an echo statement to retain the escaped quotes as it's written into the new text file.

I've tried various iterations of sed, tr, etc. echo -e and printf. Mostly I had no luck.

Right now I'm able to remove all between  tags with...

```
echo $line | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' >> $JSON_FILE_FILTERED
```

...which somewhat works but it wont correct other double quotes within a data bracket

```
{"description": "Here is some text with \"Some Big Guy's\" hat"}
```

```
{"description": "Here is some text with "Some Big Guy's" hat"}
```

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) points out that `read` without `-r` will [mangle backslashes](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162)

Comment: Try using 'jq' for processing JSON file. The file size may be a challenge, but unless you know for sure how the input is broken into lines, it is going to be hard to write a bash reader. If you know input is pretty-printed, bash

Comment: Can you share sample lines that need to be extracted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the `echo` command but the `read` command who removes the backslashes.
Please try instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *"\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"US\\\","* ]]; then
        echo "$line" >> "$JSON_FILE_FILTERED"
    fi
done < "$JSON_FILE"
```

- You need to add `-r` option to `read` to preserve the backslashes
  as a part of the line.
- You have an unnecessary left paren `(` between the [[ and ]]. (Typo?)
- You need to escape the backslashes between the [[ and ]].
- You need to enclose the variables with double quotes.

However it is still inefficient to read 20GB file with a bash script.
It will be better to say:

```
grep -F '"\"country_code\":\"US\","' file.json > filtered.json
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you greatly. That got me in the right direction by using read -r in my while loop. I didn't need to use grep for the secondary filter file because reading line-by-line in the while loop instead of value/key pairs sped things up considerably.

Comment: @LanceWig Good to know it helped. If you are confortable with my answer, would you please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer?  BR.